# Expressions Generating Errors

Tags: java, language-design

I just learned recently that C++ allows for legal code like:

```
12; //just an expression -- expression statement to be exact
int i = 45;
(i > 0) ? i-- : 1;
```

Altghough it may not be best pracitce, I can see some useful situations in which using an expression as a full statement could help. So, I was just wondering, why isn't there a similar feature in Java? What was the reason for prohibiting code like the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    func() + 1; // ERROR: NOT A STATEMENT
}

public static int func(){
    return 34;
}
```

Comment: relevant [Java: Not a statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599183/java-not-a-statement)

Comment: @FastSnail My post is completely different than the link you provided; I'm asking why expression statements or a similar feature like that in C++ isn't included in Java.

Comment: "I can see some useful situations in which using an expression as a full statement could help." Name one. Like why would there ever be an upside in using `f() + 1;` over `f();` (which is of course also an expression statement, but one that's allowed in Java).

Comment: This might be so because C++ is pass by reference and uses pointers. A function in java can make changes anywhere in memory. So, doing things with it makes sense. But Java cant do that. Java methods return a value. And that value has to be stored somewhere to be user. f() +1; has no meaning as it does nothing at all. This particular example also does nothing in C++ but maybe there are stuff that can be done with pointers like this, inline. Hence they have kept it in C++ while it is not present in Java.

Comment: @SamratDutta Since any modern compiler almost certainly removes any side-effect free expression from the code, it won't have any effect on anything in C or C++ either. It's simply allowed because no one thought to disallow it and/or because it keeps the language definition simpler. There still isn't any point to it though.

Comment: A function in C++ i meant. I wrote Java. Where is the edit button by the comment!!! Ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Altghough it may not be best pracitce, I can see some useful situations in which using an expression as a full statement could help

Using an expression as a statement (like say `System.out.println("hello")`) is perfectly allowed in Java. It's just that they made an explicit exception for expressions that are always side-effect free (like arithmetic expressions). There are no situations where using a side-effect-free expression as a statement has any effect (useful or otherwise).

> So, I was just wondering, why isn't there a similar feature in Java?

You have it the wrong way around: It's a feature in Java that's missing in C.

The reason that something like `42;` is allowed in C and not in Java is that in the C standard's grammar definition there's a rule `<stmnt> ::= <expression> ';'`. The same rule exists in Java, but in Java they added an exception that makes it illegal to apply this rule to expressions that are always side effect free. They added this rule because code like this would never have any effect and since a programmer would be unlikely to write pointless code on purpose, it's most likely an error and should thus be treated as one.

Note that the only downside of adding the exception is that it makes the standard slightly more complicated (by adding an exception to the grammar) and it makes the implementation slightly harder (because now the compiler needs to detect code like this and produce an error for this - though it should be noted that most, if not all, C and C++ compilers that are used today also detect code like this and produce a warning for this).

Comment: Note that in C#, code like `a + b;` *could* have side-effects (even though it really shouldn't), but it's also not allowed.