# How to write a heart equation

Tags: kotlin, shapes, equation

I'm trying to position 100 hundred particles in a heart shape.
The particles are circles and have a x and y position in the pane.

[image: This is what happens]

```
for (p in ps) {
    val index = ps.indexOf(p).toDouble()
    var x = 16 * Math.pow(Math.sin(index * angle.toDouble()), 3.0)
    //var y = Math.sqrt(Math.cos(index)) * Math.cos(400 * index) + Math.sqrt(Math.abs(index) - 0.4) * Math.pow((4 - index * index), 0.1)
    var y = (13 * Math.cos(index * angle.toDouble()))
        -(5 * Math.cos(2 * index * angle.toDouble()))
        -(2 * Math.cos(3 * index * angle.toDouble()))
        -(Math.cos(4 * index * angle.toDouble()))

    p.layoutX = startX + x
    p.layoutY = startY + y
}
```

p = particle

ps = particles (list)

I have no idea what I did wrong with the equation implementation.
I also tried to use Math.toRadians in cos, sin since I read that they require that to work.

Comment: you should use `ps.withIndex().forEach { (p, index) ->` instead of `for (p in ps) { val index = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                val index = -ps.size + ps.indexOf(p).toDouble()
                val angle = 360 / ps.size

                var i = index * angle
                var x = 16 * Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)), 3.0)
                var y = 13 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) -
                        (5 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(2 * i)))
                -(2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(3 * i)))
                -(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(4 * i)))
```

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR;**
Move the calculation for `y` into one line:

```
var y = (13 * Math.cos(index * angle.toDouble())) - (5 * Math.cos(2 * index * angle.toDouble())) - (2 * Math.cos(3 * index * angle.toDouble())) - (Math.cos(4 * index * angle.toDouble()))
```

**Longer explanation:**

This is an interesting question, especially with regards to Kotlin. A quick (popular search engine name here) search tells me that the formula you're using is:

```
x(T)=16sin^3(T) 
y(T)=13cos(T)−5cos(2T)−2cos(3T)−cos(4T)
```

Looking at your code, everything seems to be fine...except for the 3 calculations for `y`, each on new line, and this is the culprit of your "issue", because they are each treated separately, not part of `y` calculation.

This can be seen in the shape of heart:

```
val y = (13 * Math.cos(angle)).toFloat()
```

[image]

```
val y = (13 * Math.cos(angle) - 5 * Math.cos(2 * angle)).toFloat()
```

[image]

```
val y = (13 * Math.cos(angle) - 5 * Math.cos(2 * angle) - 2 * Math.cos(3 * angle)).toFloat()
```

[image]

```
val y = (13 * Math.cos(angle) - 5 * Math.cos(2 * angle) - 2 * Math.cos(3 * angle) - Math.cos(4 * angle)).toFloat()
```

[image]

Look at these (Kotlin):

```
var sum = 10 + 10

println("sum=$sum") // prints sum=20

sum = 10 + 10
+ 10

println("sum=$sum") // also prints sum=20 (!)
```

In contrast, in Java, this is true:

```
int sum = 10 + 10;
System.out.println("sum=" + sum); // prints sum=20

sum = 10 + 10
+10;
System.out.println("sum=" + sum); // prints sum=30 (!), as expected

sum = 10 + 10;
+10; // doesn't compile
```

The compiler complains that this is ["Not a statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599183/java-not-a-statement)

---

On a separate note, there are few improvements you could do in your code (eg. extract duplications into a variable, etc.)